# The line has been modified, your changes will be discarded issue in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

The products list is dynamically generated while running purchase request. While change the cost or qty it shows the following error, What need to do to modify the record?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I fond the answer for it. I made one of the required field(UOM) in order line. So that only this happens.